# Connection Refused even after adding a new Firewall rule

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables

I am trying to connect to my local UNIX server i made from another remote device. the Server is up and listening to the port i specified. i also added a new firewall rule to open that port but still my client cannot connect. it shows ERROR CONNECTION REFUSED

here is my server code

```
int main() {
  int fd, i,svclient,rval,msg;
  int clients[10], num_clients;
  fd_set read_set,write_set;
  char buf[100];

  struct sockaddr_in addr;

  if ( (fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("socket error");
    exit(-1);
  }


  bzero((char *) &addr, sizeof(addr));
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  addr.sin_port = htons(4001);

  //strncpy(addr.sun_path, socket_path, sizeof(addr.sun_path)-1);
  //strcpy(addr.sun_path, NAME);

  if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1) {
    perror("bind error");
    exit(-1);
  }
  printf("Bind complet...\n");

  if (listen(fd, 20) == -1) {
    perror("listen error");
    exit(-1);
  }

  num_clients = 0;
  int size = sizeof(fd);

   while (1) {

    int clientfd;
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    int addrlen=sizeof(client_addr);
    FD_ZERO(&read_set);
    FD_SET(fd, &read_set);

    for (i = 0; i < num_clients; i++) { //at first this part will not excute
      FD_SET(clients[i], &read_set);
    }

    select(fd + num_clients + 1, &read_set, NULL, NULL, NULL);


    if (FD_ISSET(fd, &read_set)) {
      if ( (clients[num_clients++] = accept(fd,(struct sockaddr*)&client_addr,&addrlen)) == -1) {
        perror("accept error");
        continue;
      }
      /*printf("incoming message..................... !\n \n");*/
      printf("%s:%d connected\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));
    }


    for (i = 0; i < num_clients; i++) {

      if (FD_ISSET(clients[i], &read_set)) {
        msg = read(clients[i], buf, sizeof(buf));
        if(msg > 0){
          buf[msg] = 0;
          int savedclnt = clients[i];
          printf("%s \n \n", buf);

          /*for(int p=0;p<num_clients;p++)
          {
            if( clients[p]!= savedclnt){
              write(clients[p],buf,msg);
            }

          }*/
        }

      }

    }
  }
}
```

and my client

```
int main( )
{   

    struct uci_context *uci;
    uci = uci_init();
    int sockfd;
    int ret;
    struct sockaddr_in dest;
    struct addrinfo hint, *res = NULL;
    struct hostent *host;
    char *hostip;
    char *string;



    if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0 )
    {
        puts("Unble to create socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    hostip = ucix_get_option(uci, "pack_mon", "pack_monitoring", "address");
    string = ucix_get_option(uci, "pack_mon", "pack_monitoring", "port");

    bzero(&dest, sizeof(dest));
    dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dest.sin_port = htons(atoi(string));

    memset(&hint, '\0', sizeof hint);
    hint.ai_family = PF_UNSPEC;
    hint.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICHOST;

    printf(" %s- %s\n", hostip, string );



    if(isdigit(hostip[0])){
        ret = getaddrinfo(hostip, NULL, &hint, &res);// this is more efficient than inet_addr

        if (ret) {

            exit(1);
        }
    }else if( (host = gethostbyname(hostip)) != 0){

        strncpy((char*)&dest.sin_addr , (char*)host->h_addr , sizeof dest.sin_addr);

    }else{

        exit(1);
        printf("cannot resolve ip address");
    }  


    if ( connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, sizeof(dest)) < 0 )
    {
        printf("%d\n", connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, sizeof(dest)) < 0);
        perror("hmmmm" );
        exit(1);
    }else{
        printf("%d\n", connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, sizeof(dest)) < 0);
        printf("Port number %s is open.....\n",string);
    }


    char *message;
    message = "help";
    write(sockfd,message,strlen(message));


    close(sockfd);
    freeaddrinfo(res);
    return 0;
}
```

FIREWALL RULE

sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 4001 -j ACCEPT

Iptable output:

~/Desktop$ sudo iptables -L -v --line-numbers

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        8   440 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:4001
2        3   120 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:5001
3     177K  128M ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
4     177K  128M ufw-before-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
5      801 58737 ufw-after-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
6      208  7160 ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
7      208  7160 ufw-reject-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
8      208  7160 ufw-track-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
9        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
10       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
11       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:4999

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
2        0     0 ufw-before-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
3        0     0 ufw-after-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
4        0     0 ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
5        0     0 ufw-reject-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
6        0     0 ufw-track-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1     154K   19M ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
2     154K   19M ufw-before-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
3     3925  241K ufw-after-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
4     3925  241K ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
5     3925  241K ufw-reject-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
6     3925  241K ufw-track-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1      232 18312 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns
2        0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm
3        0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:netbios-ssn
4        0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:microsoft-ds
5       27  9365 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
6        0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
7      334 23900 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1      208  7160 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
3        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp source-quench
4        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
5        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
6        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
7        0     0 ufw-user-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1    20690 2045K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
2     155K  126M ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
3        3  1434 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
4        3  1434 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
5        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
6        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp source-quench
7        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
8        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
9        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
10       4  1342 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:bootps dpt:bootpc
11    1351  103K ufw-not-local  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
12     542 44077 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             224.0.0.251          udp dpt:mdns
13       0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
14     809 59217 ufw-user-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1    20701 2046K ACCEPT     all  --  any    lo      anywhere             anywhere            
2     129K   17M ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
3     3925  241K ufw-user-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        3  1434 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
2        0     0 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1       23  1510 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
2      736 50285 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
3      592 51499 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
4        0     0 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10
5        0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1      593 51577 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1     3755  225K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW
2      110 12370 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        8   480 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:5001
2        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:4001

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
2        0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

And its Listening on that port

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       138595      18347/m         
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          18805       -
```

Comment: Please add the output of `iptables -n -L`

Comment: Try to **temporarily** disable the firewall entirely via `sudo ufw disable`. Does your server even listen on the port? Check `netstat -tulpen` for your ports.

Comment: Yes it is listening on that port

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       138595      18347/m

Comment: Your server code contains port 5001, not 4001, maybe a typo?

Comment: i changed the port, its 4001 .  Not a typo

Comment: So, if you can't connect even if the firewall is disabled, I doubt it's an iptables / ufw problem

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between -A (append) option of command and -I (insert) option. When you append a rule there could be another existing rule which comes before which forbids connection.

Try using -I option.

Comment: Still Refusing connection